# How to emulate user connection to web page

Tags: c#

I want to emulate many users connection and emulate mane requests to concrete site page from C# code on my site. How can I do this? Site have shared ip.

Comment: If you are looking for tools - it would be off-topic on SO, if you are looking for coding advice `HttpClient` may be starting point, but you need to provide more details to get concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best load testing tools out there is JMeter: http://jmeter.apache.org/

Additionally, you could use Visual Studio Load test built-in tool to do it as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx

Comment: +1 from me ! I was not aware of this tool, thanks for valuable info !